# Flutter firebase_ui_oauth plugin how to launch my app after login?

Tags: flutter, firebase, plugins, firebase-authentication, oauth

Well, I was using the original Firebase plugin for auth, but it's been deprecated. So I'm refactoring to use the current [firebase_ui_oauth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_oauth) plugin, and, frustratingly, I can't see from Google's example how to launch the app after authentication. Bit of a rookie stumble methinks.

This is Google's example main.dart from [Github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example/lib/main.dart)

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
      hide PhoneAuthProvider, EmailAuthProvider;
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_localizations/firebase_ui_localizations.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_apple/firebase_ui_oauth_apple.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_facebook/firebase_ui_oauth_facebook.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_twitter/firebase_ui_oauth_twitter.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
    
    import 'config.dart';
    import 'decorations.dart';
    import 'firebase_options.dart';
    
    final actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings(
      url: 'https://flutterfire-e2e-tests.firebaseapp.com',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      androidMinimumVersion: '1',
      androidPackageName: 'io.flutter.plugins.firebase_ui.firebase_ui_example',
      iOSBundleId: 'io.flutter.plugins.fireabaseUiExample',
    );
    final emailLinkProviderConfig = EmailLinkAuthProvider(
      actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings,
    );
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    
      FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
        EmailAuthProvider(),
        emailLinkProviderConfig,
        PhoneAuthProvider(),
        GoogleProvider(clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
        AppleProvider(),
        FacebookProvider(clientId: FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID),
        TwitterProvider(
          apiKey: TWITTER_API_KEY,
          apiSecretKey: TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY,
          redirectUri: TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI,
        ),
      ]);
    
      runApp(const FirebaseAuthUIExample());
    }
    
    // Overrides a label for en locale
    // To add localization for a custom language follow the guide here:
    // https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#an-alternative-class-for-the-apps-localized-resources
    class LabelOverrides extends DefaultLocalizations {
      const LabelOverrides();
    
      @override
      String get emailInputLabel => 'Enter your email';
    }
    
    class FirebaseAuthUIExample extends StatelessWidget {
      const FirebaseAuthUIExample({super.key});
    
      String get initialRoute {
        final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
        if (auth.currentUser == null) {
          return '/';
        }
    
        if (!auth.currentUser!.emailVerified && auth.currentUser!.email != null) {
          return '/verify-email';
        }
    
        return '/profile';
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final buttonStyle = ButtonStyle(
          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(12)),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          ),
        );
    
        final mfaAction = AuthStateChangeAction<MFARequired>(
          (context, state) async {
            final nav = Navigator.of(context);
    
            await startMFAVerification(
              resolver: state.resolver,
              context: context,
            );
    
            nav.pushReplacementNamed('/profile');
          },
        );
    
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
            useMaterial3: true,
            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(style: buttonStyle),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(style: buttonStyle),
            outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(style: buttonStyle),
          ),
          initialRoute: initialRoute,
          routes: {
            '/': (context) {
              return SignInScreen(
                actions: [
                  ForgotPasswordAction((context, email) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                      context,
                      '/forgot-password',
                      arguments: {'email': email},
                    );
                  }),
                  VerifyPhoneAction((context, _) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/phone');
                  }),
                  AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
                    if (!state.user!.emailVerified) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                    }
                  }),
                  AuthStateChangeAction<UserCreated>((context, state) {
                    if (!state.credential.user!.emailVerified) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                    }
                  }),
                  AuthStateChangeAction<CredentialLinked>((context, state) {
                    if (!state.user.emailVerified) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                    }
                  }),
                  mfaAction,
                  EmailLinkSignInAction((context) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/email-link-sign-in');
                  }),
                ],
                styles: const {
                  EmailFormStyle(signInButtonVariant: ButtonVariant.filled),
                },
                headerBuilder: headerImage('assets/images/flutterfire_logo.png'),
                sideBuilder: sideImage('assets/images/flutterfire_logo.png'),
                subtitleBuilder: (context, action) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      action == AuthAction.signIn
                          ? 'Welcome to Firebase UI! Please sign in to continue.'
                          : 'Welcome to Firebase UI! Please create an account to continue',
                    ),
                  );
                },
                footerBuilder: (context, action) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                      child: Text(
                        action == AuthAction.signIn
                            ? 'By signing in, you agree to our terms and conditions.'
                            : 'By registering, you agree to our terms and conditions.',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            '/verify-email': (context) {
              return EmailVerificationScreen(
                headerBuilder: headerIcon(Icons.verified),
                sideBuilder: sideIcon(Icons.verified),
                actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings,
                actions: [
                  EmailVerifiedAction(() {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                  }),
                  AuthCancelledAction((context) {
                    FirebaseUIAuth.signOut(context: context);
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                  }),
                ],
              );
            },
            '/phone': (context) {
              return PhoneInputScreen(
                actions: [
                  SMSCodeRequestedAction((context, action, flowKey, phone) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
                      '/sms',
                      arguments: {
                        'action': action,
                        'flowKey': flowKey,
                        'phone': phone,
                      },
                    );
                  }),
                ],
                headerBuilder: headerIcon(Icons.phone),
                sideBuilder: sideIcon(Icons.phone),
              );
            },
            '/sms': (context) {
              final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments
                  as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    
              return SMSCodeInputScreen(
                actions: [
                  AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/profile');
                  })
                ],
                flowKey: arguments?['flowKey'],
                action: arguments?['action'],
                headerBuilder: headerIcon(Icons.sms_outlined),
                sideBuilder: sideIcon(Icons.sms_outlined),
              );
            },
            '/forgot-password': (context) {
              final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments
                  as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    
              return ForgotPasswordScreen(
                email: arguments?['email'],
                headerMaxExtent: 200,
                headerBuilder: headerIcon(Icons.lock),
                sideBuilder: sideIcon(Icons.lock),
              );
            },
            '/email-link-sign-in': (context) {
              return EmailLinkSignInScreen(
                actions: [
                  AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                  }),
                ],
                provider: emailLinkProviderConfig,
                headerMaxExtent: 200,
                headerBuilder: headerIcon(Icons.link),
                sideBuilder: sideIcon(Icons.link),
              );
            },
            '/profile': (context) {
              final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
    
              return ProfileScreen(
                actions: [
                  SignedOutAction((context) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                  }),
                  mfaAction,
                ],
                actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings,
                showMFATile: kIsWeb ||
                    platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
                    platform == TargetPlatform.android,
              );
            },
          },
          title: 'Firebase UI demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          locale: const Locale('en'),
          localizationsDelegates: [
            FirebaseUILocalizations.withDefaultOverrides(const LabelOverrides()),
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            FirebaseUILocalizations.delegate,
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Where can I put my `return MyHomePage(userId: result.uid);` and let the user crack on?

Comment: You must be getting the callback when the Firebase Auth screen has completed authentication process so that's when you should open any screen that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just needed to fire it up in an emulator to understand it, doh.

```
      String get initialRoute {
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    if (auth.currentUser == null) {
      return '/';
    }

    if (!auth.currentUser!.emailVerified && auth.currentUser!.email != null) {
      return '/verify-email';
    }

    return '/profile';
  }
```

Basically, this tests if the user (1) is logged in (2) is verified

If both of those are passed, then it defaults to launching a profile screen.

So the '/profile' route is where you can hijack the entry flow to launch your app. And reconfigure that screen for somewhere else.

My apologies for wasting people's attention 
x
Sam